# Segmentation fault using snprintf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm getting a weird segmentation fault using snprintf.

Here is my code:

```
size_t tmp_size = win_data_width; // win_data_width is the width of a Ncurses window

char *tmp = new(tmp_size);   // <------- new == malloc MACRO
snprintf(tmp,
    tmp_size,
    "%-15.20s"       /* Process name */
    "%10u"           /* PID          */
    " %-15.10s"      /* Operation    */
    "%-50.45s"       /* Path         */
    "%-10.10s"       /* Result       */
    " %-200.200s\n", /* Details      */

    i->pname,
    i->pid,
    i->operation,
    i->path,
    i->result,
    i->details
);
```

And this is the GDB `bt` full output:

```
#0  __strnlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strnlen.S:34
No locals.
#1  0x00007ffff7400e09 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffdb80, format=<optimized out>,
    format@entry=0x402f38 "%-15.20s%10u %-15.10s%-50.45s%-10.10s %-200.200s\n", ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffdce8) at vfprintf.c:1655
        len = <optimized out>
        string_malloced = <optimized out>
        step0_jumps = {0, -11263, -4214, -4124, -4027, -3937, -3826, -3532, -3116, -2815, -2692, -1937, -2239, -2139, -1766, -16687, 265, 280, 47,
          2130, -15904, -28, 883, -5283, -5210, -17380, 567, -2039, -2139, -3638}
        space = 0
        is_short = 0
        use_outdigits = 0
        step1_jumps = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2815, -2692, -1937, -2239, -2139, -1766, -16687, 265, 280, 47, 2130, -15904, -28, 883, -5283,
          -5210, -17380, 567, -2039, -2139, 0}
        group = 0
        prec = 10
        step2_jumps = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2692, -1937, -2239, -2139, -1766, -16687, 265, 280, 47, 2130, -15904, -28, 883, -5283, -5210,
          -17380, 567, -2039, -2139, 0}
        string = <optimized out>
        left = 1
        is_long_double = 0
        width = 10
        step3a_jumps = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2037, 0, 0, 0, -1766, -16687, 265, 280, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, -5283, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        alt = 0
        showsign = 0
        is_long = 0
        is_char = 0
        pad = 32 ' '
        step3b_jumps = {0 <repeats 11 times>, -2239, 0, 0, -1766, -16687, 265, 280, 47, 2130, -15904, -28, 883, -5283, -5210, -17380, 567, 0, 0, 0}
        step4_jumps = {0 <repeats 14 times>, -1766, -16687, 265, 280, 47, 2130, -15904, -28, 883, -5283, -5210, -17380, 567, 0, 0, 0}
        is_negative = <optimized out>
        number = <optimized out>
        base = <optimized out>
        the_arg = {pa_wchar = 0 L'\000', pa_int = 0, pa_long_int = 0, pa_long_long_int = 0, pa_u_int = 0, pa_u_long_int = 0, pa_u_long_long_int = 0,
        pa_double = 0, pa_long_double = 0, pa_string = 0x0, pa_wstring = 0x0, pa_pointer = 0x0, pa_user = 0x0}
        spec = 115 's'
        _buffer = {__routine = 0x1, __arg = 0x7ffff779ac94, __canceltype = 6313844, __prev = 0x7ffff74c3a84 <___vsprintf_chk+148>}
        _avail = <optimized out>
        thousands_sep = 0x0
        grouping = 0xffffffffffffffff <Address 0xffffffffffffffff out of bounds>
        done = 91
        f = 0x402f5c "s %-200.200s\n"
        lead_str_end = 0x402f38 "%-15.20s%10u %-15.10s%-50.45s%-10.10s %-200.200s\n"
        end_of_spec = <optimized out>
        work_buffer = "\001\200\255\373\000\000\000\000tW`\000\000\000\000\000tW`\000\000\000\000\000tW`\000\000\000\000\000tW`\000\000\000\000\000wW`\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377tW`\000\000\000\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377", '\000' <repeats 40 times>, "d\000\000\000\004\000\000\000QX`", '\000' <repeats 21 times>, "\020\000\000\000\000\000\000\000CX`\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000[C\033[\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\330\377\377\377\177\000\000\000\330\377\377\377\177\000\000\377\377\377\377\000\000\000\000"...
        workstart = 0x0
        workend = 0x7fffffffdb38 "\200\333\377\377\377\177"
        ap_save = {{gp_offset = 24, fp_offset = 48, overflow_arg_area = 0x7fffffffddc0, reg_save_area = 0x7fffffffdd00}}
        nspecs_done = 4
        save_errno = 0
        readonly_format = 0
        args_malloced = 0x0
        specs = 0x7fffffffd670
        specs_malloced = false
        jump_table = "\001\000\000\004\000\016\000\006\000\000\a\002\000\003\t\000\005\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\032\000\031\000\023\023\023\000\035\000\000\f\000\000\000\000\000\000\025\000\000\000\000\022\000\r\000\000\000\000\000\000\032\000\024\017\023\023\023\n\017\034\000\v\030\027\021\026\f\000\025\033\020\000\000\022\000\r"
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "_IO_vfprintf_internal"
#2  0x00007ffff7427655 in _IO_vsnprintf (
    string=0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)",
    maxlen=<optimized out>, format=0x402f38 "%-15.20s%10u %-15.10s%-50.45s%-10.10s %-200.200s\n", args=args@entry=0x7fffffffdce8) at vsnprintf.c:119
        sf = {f = {_sbf = {_f = {_flags = -72515583,
                _IO_read_ptr = 0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)",
                _IO_read_base = 0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)",
                _IO_write_base = 0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)", _IO_write_ptr = 0x646beb "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)", _IO_write_end = 0x646c20 "\240",
                _IO_buf_base = 0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)", _IO_buf_end = 0x646c20 "\240", _IO_save_base = 0x0, _IO_backup_base = 0x0, _IO_save_end = 0x0, _markers = 0x0, _chain = 0x0, _fileno = 0,
                _flags2 = 0, _old_offset = 4151907146, _cur_column = 0, _vtable_offset = 0 '\000', _shortbuf = "", _lock = 0x0, _offset = 0,
                _codecvt = 0x0, _wide_data = 0x0, _freeres_list = 0x0, _freeres_buf = 0x7fff00000000, _freeres_size = 0, _mode = -1,
                _unused2 = "\377\177\000\000\000\000\000\024\000\000\000\000\260\260>\367\377\177\000"}, vtable = 0x7ffff7773fa0 <_IO_strn_jumps>},
            _s = {_allocate_buffer = 0x0, _free_buffer = 0x650450}},
          overflow_buf = "-\a\000\000\000\000\000\000\340\005e\000\000\000\000\000\"\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\"", '\000' <repeats 15 times>, "@Ww\367\377\177\000\000\222\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\060\030@\000\000\000\000"}
        ret = <optimized out>
#3  0x00007ffff7408142 in __snprintf (s=<optimized out>, maxlen=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at snprintf.c:34
        arg = {{gp_offset = 48, fp_offset = 48, overflow_arg_area = 0x7fffffffddd0, reg_save_area = 0x7fffffffdd00}}
        done = 10
#4  0x0000000000401d88 in get_str_info (i=0x6441b0) at ui.c:13
        tmp_size = 146
        tmp = 0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)"
#5  0x0000000000402154 in draw_data (in=0x643dd0) at ui.c:118
        s_info = 0x646b90 "0Bd", ' ' <repeats 20 times>, "49  Nd", ' ' <repeats 62 times>, "Ok         Read 8 bytes (was requested to read 16)"
        i = 10
#6  0x00000000004028c3 in read_from_socket (sock_fd=7) at procmon-viewer.c:276
        x = 0x646f10
        i = 0x646e10
#7  0x0000000000402671 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdfc8) at procmon-viewer.c:192
        n = 1
        i = 0
        ch = -1
        sock_fd = 7
        efd = 9
        stdin_fd = 8
        socket_event = {events = 1, data = {ptr = 0x40183000000007, fd = 7, u32 = 7, u64 = 18040992946978823}}
        stdin_event = {events = 1, data = {ptr = 0x8, fd = 8, u32 = 8, u64 = 8}}
        events = 0x63bb00
```

I'm completely lost. This is the first time I see such a backtrace. Why am I getting this?

I updated my code to:

```
int err;
char *tmp = malloc(win_data_width + 1);
if(!tmp){
    return NULL;
}

err = snprintf(tmp,
    win_data_width,
    "%-15.20s"       /* Process name */
    "%10u"           /* PID          */
    " %-15.10s"      /* Operation    */
    "%-50.45s"       /* Path         */
    "%-10.10s"       /* Result       */
    " %-200.200s\n", /* Details      */

    i->pname,
    i->pid,
    i->operation,
    i->path,
    i->result,
    i->details
);

if(err < 0){
    return NULL;
}
```

And I'm still getting the exact same segmentation fault. I think it's reasonable to discard a malloc/snprintf error. What else could be causing this?

`i` is a struct with a few `char *` and a `pid_t` (not a pointer to `pid_t`).

Each of the `char *` are malloc-ed before calling this function and each of them is guaranteed to have either the data it should contain or an empty string.
Maybe the size of some of the `char *` inside `i` could be bigger than win_data_width, but in that case `snprintf` is supposed to truncate the content (which is acceptable behavior for my application).

That said: I don't expect `tmp` to have *ALL* the content of each `char *`, but the maximum possible data according to `win_data_width`.

Comment: Hmmm, can we see your full code?

Comment: I could post it, but the parts of the code that are involved in this are a lot. Anyways, if you really want to see the entire code I could create another branch in GitHub and lik to there

Comment: If you feel like you need to do that, your problem is probably too complex for StackOverflow. Can you narrow it down a bit more?

Comment: if you are using pointers to any of the members you are printing, did you account for that before you 'sized' the tmt_size value?  I am suspicious that `size_t tmp_size = win_data_width;` is not accounting for the collective memory of `i->pname,`, `i->pid,`, et. al.

Comment: @ryyker That shouldn't matter at I'm using ```sNprintf```, right? I mean, it won't copy more than ```win_data_width``` bytes.

Comment: Most probable candidate is your `new()` macro. Second: check the return value from new (=malloc()) and snprintf().

Comment: @wildplasser - suggesting `new` anything on a OP tagged _C_, is in _Poor Taste_ or _Bad Form_, or simply not a good idea. (see others comments on that :)

Comment: @ryyker What is wrong with bad taste? Secondly: I am not suggesting it, I am only suggesting that the stuff inside the `new()` macro is the underlying cause of the bug.

Comment: @alexandernst - is it feasible that each member of struct could have win_data_width?  If that is the case, then the ***[snprintf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)*** function still may not work correctly, especially if the struct members have not been allocated memory _if needed_ (i.e. if they are created `int *pid;`, etc)

Comment: @ryyker I'm not really sure I understand your question. Anyways, ```i``` is a struct with a few ```char *``` and a ```pid_t``` (not a pointer to ```pid_t```). Each of the ```char *``` are malloc-ed before calling this function. Maybe the size of some of the ```char *``` could be bigger than ```win_data_width```, but I can't see why will this segfault. Isn't snprintf supposed to trim what it can't print to the given char?

Comment: `if(err < 0){` should be `if(err < 0|| err >= win_data_width  ){` Plus: as @ryyker said: the structure elements could be NULL, uninitialised or unterminated strings.

Comment: @wildplasser Ok, the second condition will make my function to return always ```NULL```, which means that snprintf truncated my string (which is an acceptable behavior). Anyways, this still isn't fixing my segfault.

Comment: Please see my edit again

Comment: BTW your NULL return on error (first edit) will leak memory. Why not simply use an automatic bufffer ("on the stack")

Comment: @wildplasser Ah, indeed. It will leak memory. But that's not the problem anyways. I could use stack instead of heap, but that really won't change anything, except some speed improvement (which I don't need right now)

Comment: Try it (could be that your memory arena is already corrupted) Another possibility is that the `i` struct contains pointers to memory that has been freed, or to automatic memory that has gone out of scope ("stale pointers")

Comment: Note: To insure compatibility, cast `i->pid` to the type that matches your format specifier.  IOW `(unsigned) i->pid`.

Comment: What happens if you do `puts(i->name);puts(i->operation);puts(i->path);puts(i->result);puts(i->details);`?  Are you sure that `i->pid` is a 32 bit type?  And what platform is this?

Comment: @MichaelBurr - I ran some tests with un-terminated members and passed into `snprintf()` with only a "unitialized before access" error, but no segfault.  I think we need to see enough real code to compile ourselves before really understanding what is going on.  An un-terminated string will segfault `fputs()`, but evidently not `snprintf()`

Comment: @alexandernst: just curious if this ever got resolved.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Indeed, it got fixed. I have a list of prev<-i->next struct, and the problem was that after some time, the items added first got deleted (which means I was passing pointers to random data).

Answer (score 1):

You should code (if coding in C++)

```
 char *tmp = new char [tmp_size];
```

(and perhaps even use `tmp_size+1`)

or (if coding in plain C)

```
 char* tmp = malloc(tmp_size);
 if (!tmp) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

`char *tmp = new(tmp_size);` should probably not compile. And

```
 char *tmp = new char(tmp_size);
```

is (in C++) incorrectly allocating one single `char` on the heap initialized to  `tmp_size`.

Remember that `new` is a keyword in C++. Avoid using that word in C. Having a macro or function named `new` in plain C is poor taste.

<sup>Because some people only use a C++ compiler, even for C code.</sup>

In many C programs a function which always successfully `malloc` (and terminates on failure of `malloc`) is conventionally called    `xmalloc`:

```
static inline void* xmalloc(size_t sz) {
   void* p = malloc(sz);
   if (!p) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "xmalloc failed for %zd bytes: %s\n",
             sz, strerror(errno));
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
   };
   return p;
}
```

Don't call that `new` in C!

BTW, always check for failure of `malloc`; lower your memory limit with `ulimit` bash builtin to test that.

And you should consider using [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) if your system has it.

If your code is crashing you might have corrupted the heap memory (elsewhere). Surely using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) should help.

Comment: Why are you suggesting it? Isn't malloc enough?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see the confusion. By bad. ```new``` is a MACRO which just calls ```malloc```

Comment: @alexandernst and _that's_ why we need to see the rest of your code!

Comment: _poor taste_, is that the same as _bad form_ ?  The OP is clearly tagged C, not C++.

Comment: Ok, ```new``` is arguably not a good taste, but that doesn't explain why is my code failing. According to the backtrace malloc isn't the cause of the failure (even further, I just patches my code for checking if malloc error-ed, and I keep getting the same segfault)

Comment: Use `valgrind` as I am suggesting.

Comment: I'm not sure how valgrind is going to help me here. How can I check if I'm corrupting the stack?

Comment: `You should code in C++` No, he should _not_. **You** should answer in C, which is the language tag for this question.

Comment: I think C programmers should worry about not using identifiers like `new` in C programs when the C++ folks stop using classes and templates to ensure their code will compile as C. What's next? Avoid the use of variable length arrays, and start casting the return from `malloc()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look closely at memory allocation of all struct members before  calling `snprintf()` .  If there are any null pointers, any string operations that are expecting a null terminator will fail, potentially generating your seg-fault.

```
int snprintf (char Target_String[], size_t Buffer_Size, const char Format_String[], ...);
```

Here are the specifics:
***snprintf()`*** - Writes output to the specified string according to format specifiers in formatString. A null character is written at the end of the characters written. *(nothing is said here about if a null pointer is passed though)*.

If the resulting formatted string is more than bufferSize - 1 bytes long (not including the terminating null character), only the first bufferSize - 1 characters plus a null character are written to targetString. The function always returns the full length of the formatted string, which is greater than bufferSize only if truncation occurs.

This is why it has been suggested that you check the output of `snprintf()`, ***always*** (not just for negative values).  Address all issues around your call to this particular function, and I suspect your seg-fault will not occur.

`#define WIN_DATA_WIDTH          0x0018` is a definition I found [here]9https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/kernel-next/+/refs/heads/master/include/pcmcia/cs.h0).  I am not sure if that is what it is in your environment.  0x0018 is decimal 24 bytes.

***[EDIT]***

Doing what a I have illustrated below (the best I can do without seeing how you have allocated memory for your char * members of struct i), I get no segfault here:  Try this in your compiler, and see what you get.  (when the function returns, `tmp` is holding only 24 bytes as malloc'ed, err is set to 303, but no segfault)  Also, if I pass the members to I without allocating memory, `struct I` get a runtime error, *referenced before being initialized*, but that is not fatal.  A segfault of course always is.

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

typedef struct {
    char *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
    char *d;
    char *e;
    char *f;
    char *g;
}I;

int main(void)
{

        I k;
        k.a = malloc(24); sprintf(k.a, "%f", 12343.432524524);
        k.b = malloc(24); sprintf(k.b, "%f", 535.45645646464); 
        k.c = malloc(24); sprintf(k.c, "%f", 4.4564456645645); 
        k.d = malloc(24); sprintf(k.d, "%f", 456.644564564564); 
        k.e = malloc(24); sprintf(k.e, "%f", 5.4564564564564); 
        k.f = malloc(24); sprintf(k.f, "%f", 45.456456456456); 


    size_t tmp_size = 0x0018; // win_data_width is the width of a Ncurses window

    char *tmp = malloc(tmp_size);   // <------- new == malloc MACRO

        err = snprintf(tmp,
                tmp_size,
                "%-15.20s"       /* Process name */
                "%10u"           /* PID          */
                " %-15.10s"      /* Operation    */
                "%-50.45s"       /* Path         */
                "%-10.10s"       /* Result       */
                " %-200.200s\n", /* Details      */

                k.a,
                k.b,
                k.c,
                k.d,
                k.e,
                k.f
    );  ///////////////////////////////////////   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ***i is a struct with a few char * and a pid_t (not a pointer to pid_t).***  post the code segment showing how you prep the struct members, before they are passed as arguments to `snprintf()`.  Clearly, if you are getting a seg fault, right at the execution flow of calling this function, something is wrong with one or more of the arguments.  Sorry, I have to walk away for while.  But if you post something else meaningful, I am sure someone will run with it.

Comment: @alexandernst -  Okay, I have tried to reconstruct the scenario best I can without seeing how your struct is built, and I get no segfault.  Compare what I have with what you have and see what pops out.